# Create a list for Attendance tracking and a column that determines if the logged time is late or not

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I want to create a simple SharePoint list with a form that only asks for three things: Team the person belongs to, Choose between LOGIN or LOGOUT, and Shift Schedule from a dropdown menu. Each Shift Schedule has a fixed login time. For example 7:00am. So I use the Created field as it already captures the time the person created the item for LOGIN or LOGOUT. Lets say the person creates the item at 1:05pm. Which means he/she is late 5 minutes. So I want to add a new column for "Status" which displays "Late" or "On Time". What should be my formula for the "Status" column to calculate correctly if the person is late or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula

```
=IF([LOGIN/LOGOUT]="LOGIN",IF(VALUE(TEXT([Created],"hhmmss"))>70000,"Late","On Time"),"")
```

Here is my testing results:

[image]

*(As I need to get the testing results, I use “date” time instead of “Created” time.)*